# http NewRequest get unexpected characters

Tags: http, go, get

I try to parse a page with this code :

```
client := &http.Client{}
profile := getEpiURL(login)

log.Print("Fetch " + profile)
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", profile, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.AddCookie(cookieSessionIntra)
body, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
```

With this as getEpiURL function :

```
func getEpiURL(login string) (url string) {
    url = "https://********/user/" + login + "/?format=json"
    return
}
```

And when i look at the output the `profile` variable is good, but in the Request it seems obviously wrong...

> 2016/11/24 12:53:53 Fetch https://********/user/le****in-vi**rd@e*******/?format=json

Then the debug for the request prints me :

> GET /user/%00l%*****0o%***00.%00c***0-%00v%00i%0*a%00r%00d%00@%00e%0**0i%00t%00e%00c%0***0.%0***00/?format=json
>   HTTP/1.1 Host: ****** User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=********* Accept-Encoding: gzip

Comment: Note the text you tried to mask out is easily visible in the percent-encoded output.

Comment: True. Not really important but next time I'll pay more attention :/

Answer (score 1):

I think your original string somehow contains NUL characters. Try this out in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L34K4a1-mM):

```
func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://some/normal/path", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground, %q", body)
}
```

You'll get:

```
"GET /normal/path HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: some...
```

Now [try it with a string in which you inserted NUL characters](https://play.golang.org/p/-pDuH_80Y-):

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://some/\000n\000o\000rmal/path", nil)
```

...

```
"GET /%00n%00o%00rmal/path HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: some...
```

Not quite sure how your string ended up containing those. Read more about [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

Comment: The part that is percent encoded is an email adress, but i need it to be not encoded... Problem is i haven't encoded it :/

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Can you show how you generate "login"? If you pay close attention to the output you posted only that part is problematic.

Comment: login came from : `csv.NewReader(file).ReadAll()` it gives me a slice of slice of string. So `ret[id][indexEmail]` is my `login`, with `indexEmail` defined as 28.